# Terraform : Access output variables of module in the YML file

Tags: terraform, yaml, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure

I am using following code to push static files to storage account using Azure CLI.

```
- stage: Apply_On_Dev
dependsOn: [Setup, Prepare, Plan_Dev, Build_Frontend_Dev]
jobs:
  - deployment: 'apply'
    displayName: Dev
    environment: dev
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - template: terraform-apply.yml
              parameters:
                environment: 'dev'
                environmentPath: 'dev'
                terraformStateFilename: 'frontend-devnew.tfstate'
                artifacts: 'dev_artifacts'

            - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current' # Options: current, specific
                downloadType: 'single' # Options: single, specific
                artifactName: 'drop' # Required when  downloadType == Single content
                downloadPath: '.'

            - task: AzureCLI@2
              displayName: 'Copy Frontend to storage Account'
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '$(subscription)'
                scriptType: bash
                scriptLocation: inlineScript
                inlineScript: |
                  echo "storage_account_name: $(terraform output -raw storage_account_name)"
                  echo "storage_account_primary_access_key: $(terraform output -raw module.frontend.storage_account_primary_access_key)"
                  az storage blob upload-batch -s drop -d \$web --account-name "" --account-key "" --overwrite
                addSpnToEnvironment: false
```

I would like to get the storage account name and key from output.tf in the YML file for the Azure CLI commands, how can I achieve this?

The terraform module does have output variable for the storage account (see below screen)

output.tf file

```
output "storage_account_primary_access_key" {
      value = azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_access_key
}
    
output "storage_account_name" {
      value = azurerm_storage_account.storage.name
}
```

Module Call Code

```
module "frontend" {
      source              = "../modules/frontend"
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      location            = var.location
      tags                = { Project = "Frontend", Environment = "Dev" }
}
```

Comment: Can you please remove the screenshot and add those outputs to the question? How are you calling the module, i.e., what is the name you assigned to the module call? Can you add that part of the configuration to the question as well?

Answer (score 2):

The way to use module outputs [1] is the following:

```
module.<module_name>.<output_name>
```

In your case, since it seems you already have defined the desired outputs on the module level, you can try adding the outputs in the root module by creating an `outputs.tf` file. Those outputs will reference the outputs from the module:

```
output "storage_account_name" {
  value       = module.frontend.storage_account_name
  description = "Storage account name."
}

output "storage_account_primary_access_key" {
  value       = module.frontend.storage_account_primary_access_key
  description = "Storage account primary access key."
}
```

Then, the rest echo commands and the AZ CLI command should look like this:

```yaml
...
 echo "$(terraform output -raw storage_account_name)"
 echo "$(terraform output -raw storage_account_primary_access_key)"
 az storage blob upload-batch -s drop -d \$web --account-name $(terraform output -raw storage_account_name) --account-key $(terraform output -raw storage_account_primary_access_key) --overwrite
...
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs#accessing-child-module-outputs

Comment: thanks, I will try and let you know

Comment: I am now getting below message │ Warning: No outputs found
│ 
│ The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs
│ are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output`
│ keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become available. If you are
│ using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You
│ can use the `terraform console` command to assist

Comment: Well, have you run `terraform apply` prior to running this step? Outputs will not be available until the module code was applied.

Comment: I am running terraform apply before I run Azure CLI, please see updated code block in question

Comment: Are you using Terraform workspaces?

Comment: no I am not, my code runs on Azure DevOps

Comment: Not sure about workspace but I do use tfstate which is stored in Azure Storage Account

Comment: Well, you would probably have to run the commands from the same directory where the Terraform code is located. Otherwise Terraform knows nothing about the state.

Comment: Thanks Marko, I am running this is Azure DevOps the working directory is same, However my state files are saved in Azure Storage Account

Comment: You could try by defining the state file for the output by using the `-state=<state-file-name>` option and see if that works, because it defaults to `terraform.tfstate` and it seems the state file is different in your case.

Comment: Or if possible use the `terraformStateFilename` parameter.

Comment: thanks again Mark, If you see my YAML code, I am already using state file name in the STAGE which is referring to the a state file. I am still getting same result

Comment: And the `outputs.tf` file is in `../modules/frontend`?

Comment: I have output.tf in ../modules/frontend as well as in the dev/outout.tf. So from Module I am also referring in the main DEV folder

Comment: In which of the two outputs are the outputs you want defined, `dev` or `../modules/frontend`?

Comment: My output are in module and I want to use them in YAML file

Comment: I updated the answer, can you check if that works?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have exactly done as per your code still same result

Comment: It still not working for me!! can anyone help?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that no outputs are displayed if the apply step ran successfully. I would probably inspect the state locally by running `terraform state list` and check if there are any outputs present. If so, I would then inspect the value of the output with `terraform state show <output_name>` to make sure it holds a value.

Comment: thanks @Marko, I am on it now as per your suggestions. Thanks again

Comment: it still doesn't work, I have checked everything on my side